# Why doesn't my new objects work in my main method?

Tags: java

• Add code to main that creates a new Date object named birthday. The new object
should contain your birthdate. You can use either constructor. Add code to print the date to test it.

• Add code to main that creates a new Date object named today. The new object should contain your todays date. You should use the other constructor. Add code to print the date to test it.

I have done all this and I am not sure why but my main method does not work? How would I format my code in main to do create a new object?

```
class Date {

  int year;//the next three lines are for the second bullet point
  int month;
  int day;
  int birthday;
  int today;

  public Date() {//this is the constructor that takes no parameters
    this.year = 0;
    this.month = 0;
    this.day = 0;
  }

  public Date(int year, int month, int day, int birthday, int today) { //this is for the thirs bullet point on assignment
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
    this.birthday = birthday;
    this.today = today;
  }

  public class MoreDates {

    public void printDate(Date date) {//this is for the fourth bullet point.
        System.out.println(date.year);
        System.out.println(date.month);
        System.out.println(date.day);
        System.out.println(date.birthday);
        System.out.println(date.today);
    }

    public void main(String[] args) {
        this.birthday = 17;
        this.today = 29;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `main` method doesn't do anything but assign `birthday` and `today`. Furthermore, main **must** be `public static void` - yours is not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please reduce this to a [mcve] - currently you've included a load of code and a load of irrelevant detail about your assignment, but the really important bit where you say what's wrong is just "my main method does not work". Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ as well, and bear in mind that the purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of high quality questions and answers.

Comment: You said you "have done all this", but you didn't create the `Date` `Objects` in the main method.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you create a new object using the keyword "new" and your it should look something like this

```
Date birthday=new Date();
```

Key mistake in your code:
You made the main method as part of nested class. In Java, the filename should match with the class name which has the main method. Example: If your main method is present in the class named moreDates the file name should be moreDates.java.

JVM identifies the main method by it's syntax and the expected syntax is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem:

```
class Date {

int year;//the next three lines are for the second bullet point
int month;
int day;
int birthday;
int today;

public Date() {//this is the constructor that takes no parameters
    this.year = 0;
    this.month = 0;
    this.day = 0;

}

public Date(int year, int month, int day) { //this is for the thirs bullet point on assignment
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
}
}

public class MoreDates {

    public static void printDate(Date date) {//this is for the fourth bullet point.
        System.out.println(date.year);
        System.out.println(date.month);
        System.out.println(date.day);
        System.out.println(date.birthday);
        System.out.println(date.today);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date birthday = new Date(1998,11,17);
        Date today = new Date(2016,11,29);
        printDate(birthday);
        printDate(today);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You main method is not `static`. Hence, the JVM doesn't run it when you try to execute your program.

Comment: When I add static, it says the who method is incorrect?

Comment: @Lexi yes, because a static method cannot have references to non-static content. You have a bit more refactoring to do besides making the method static, but a non-static `main` method is the reason why it won't run.